# passing multidimensional array to mysql using generated input fields

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){


$name=$_POST['name'];
$sports=$_POST['sports'];
$data=array();
for($x=0,$l=count($sports); $x<$l; $x++){
    $myArray = explode(',', $name[$x]);// you can use your own filter for names          
    foreach($myArray as $nm){
        $data[]=array('name'=>$nm,'sports'=>$sports[$x]);
    }
}
var_dump($data);


$query="INSERT INTO athletes (name, sports) VALUES ('".$data."')";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    mysqli_free_result( $result);


}

?>
```

getting error array to string conversion.
hot do i pass that in the database in separate rows.
the output is working wonderfully when i dump just the way i want it but i cant seem to get it passed to the database.

Comment: @Randy Yes that's correct.  This seems like something that is very hard to accomplish.

Comment: I've only edited to make it more obvious, I didn't actually change your question. I honestly don't have the answer for you.

Comment: ok thanks alot for doing that.

Comment: @ShannaChambers if you are asking some question and someone helps you(not mine) then you should not update your question as correct answer. Now, the viewers does not find what was the actual problem and now the question is not valid as it is already correct. Users are not here for wasting time, they are here only because they can help  someone like you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to make multidimensional array `name[][]`, you just use `name[]` so in your `PHP` code it is just like,

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$sports=$_POST['sports'];
$data=array();
for($x=0,$l=count($sports); $x<$l; $x++){
    $myArray = explode(',', $name[$x]);// you can use your own filter for names          
    foreach($myArray as $nm){
        $data[]=array('name'=>$nm,'sports'=>$sports[$x]);
    }
}
var_dump($data);
```

**[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c18e5118db616b42a6ac243d0af99e0b40bb4304)**

You can change `$data` while inserting in `database` like,

```
$data[]='("'.trim($nm).'","'.trim($sports[$x]).'")';
```

And after your loop ends you can create query like,

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO <table> (name,sports) VALUES ".implode(',',$data);
```

[Demo with Query](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d60ab0e3b4e2ac8c8f920296c7e9b663d4ec7a85)

Comment: @ Rohan Kumaram getting alot of error when i submit i just copied your code and paste

Comment: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mul.php on line 10

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mul.php on line 11

Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mul.php on line 10

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mul.php on line 11
array(0) { }

Comment: Make sure you are using `$name[$x]` and not `$name`. And see my updated answer for online demo.

Comment: i also used the update but when i press submit it gives me that error in your code you assigned the array values but in mine in mine i am passing them from the input fields. related to the demo one on the web

Comment: ok it seems like its working now i am gonna implement it so that it passes to the database thanks. i will let you know what happens

Comment: @ Rohan Kumar  got it to work but how would one insert $data in the mysql database now

Comment: You can try logic from my updated answer, may be you need to modify it, but hope it would help you.

Comment: your the best on stock overflow it works perfect i have been struggling with this for awhile now i am so thankful. Wish i could buy you a drink

Comment: i hope others who have the same problem can benefit from this question and answer.

Comment: Still your question and my answer are same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate array from post value for each row.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8aede27dc5675a8715be328dec6c5ea4c669522

Comment: got it to work but how would one insert $data in the mysql database now